# What to do with excess Culture?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

(BNW)Granted, I understand it's exceptionally difficult to adopt every social policy and ideological tenant *before* achieving any other victory condition... but I actually managed to do it by accident and kept a game running solely for meta-purposes. Technically speaking, one could force a world ideology through the world congress and adopt all new tenants for both of the ideologies they *didn't* choose, but even after that, there appears to be no recurring way of spending amassed culture, unless I've overlooked something completely and would feel like a total moron

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, there's nothing to do with excess culture.  In Brave New World, at least, having massive Culture reserves would prevent a cultural victory by some other Civ, but there's no other use for it.

Comment: This is correct. Other than social policies and tenants, there is nothing you can actually spend culture on. But with the new Cultural Victory/Tourism mechanics, another Civ must surpass your total generated culture with their total generated tourism in order to achieve the victory condition. So you can see how having an enormous amount of culture would be beneficial here. =)

Answer (score 0):

Prior to BNW, once I had got too much culture I would jump from the Autocracy / Order / Freedom trees.